# Is it posible to update ssl cert without server restarting?

Tags: node.js, ssl-certificate

I'd like to update ssl certificates on node.js http2 server without restarting (to avoid any downtime). Also I don't want to use any 3rd party modules for this work. Only pure nodejs.
Is it possible?

Right now when certificate about to expire, i just restarting the script.

```
const https = require('http2');
const server = https.createSecureServer({
  ca: fs.readFileSync('chain.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem', 'utf8'),//fullchain
  key: fs.readFileSync('privkey.pem', 'utf8'),
  allowHTTP1: true,
},
```

I expect to be able to watch if cert files were updated (using fs.watch() for example), and to update certificates in http2 server  on the fly...

Comment: Have you tried anything? I doubt nodejs is hitting the file system for every handshake, so you will likely have to restart the server in some way. You can restart the server without restarting the node application, but the server will still go down momentarily. Doing this without a server restart would likely introduce complexities on the client side as the certificate could change during an already active session.

Comment: According to the documentation [`Http2SecureServer`](https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html#http2_class_http2secureserver) extends `tls.Server` which has a method [`server.setSecureContext(options)`](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_server_setsecurecontext_options). You can try using this method to reset the certificates at runtime, but I do not know what side-effects this may have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned by Jake, setSecureContext() do the magic.
Seems it can update certificate without breaking current connections.
Something like:

```
setTimeout(function () {server.setSecureContext({
  ca: fs.readFileSync('chain.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem', 'utf8'),//fullchain
  key: fs.readFileSync('privkey.pem', 'utf8')
})},86400000)
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can just use [sniCallBack()](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createserver_options_secureconnectionlistener):

```
const https = require('http2');
const server = https.createSecureServer({
  ca: fs.readFileSync('chain.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem', 'utf8'),//fullchain
  key: fs.readFileSync('privkey.pem', 'utf8'),
  allowHTTP1: true,
  SNICallback: (servername, cb) => {
    // here you can even change up the `SecureContext`
    // based on `servername` if you want
    cb(null, server);
  }
},
```

This may be a bit outdated so try it out and ask me if anything doesn't work because the solution source code that I found [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/15115#issuecomment-326257131) is a bit different.

Comment: Thanks for point me to secureContext options. But it seems that setSecureContext() is better way than SNICallback, 'cos there still some clients which doesn't support server name extensions.